# Is this proper use of ng-init?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a MVC app that uses angularjs

(i'm over-simplifying obviously)

First my controller has this:

```
function MyController()
{
    $scope.myInit = function()
    {
         $http.get("ShowData").success(function() {
             $scope.mything = 123;
         });
    }

    // so once all my controller is defined, I call the init method
    $scope.myInit();
}
```

My view has the following code

```
@if (AllowToShowData)
{
<div><span ng-bind="{{mything}}" /></div>
}
```

Note: The http.get above and AllowToShowData are connected by the same permission. So if AllowToShowData is false, the http.get will fail also.

As you can see, if AllowToShow is true, MVC will render the section. If not, it will not render, but still the code as-is will call the myInit method which will eventually also fail.

So to avoid this scenario, I removed the call to myInit within the controller and change the view to this:

```
@if (AllowToShowData) 
{
<span ng-init="myInit()"></span>
<div><span ng-bind="{{mything}}" /></div>
}
```

This way, the myInit method gets called only when allowed and needed.

The question basically is: is this good practice for ng-init?

I don't find any other way to do it that is optimal and clean.

Thanks

Comment: The "correct" way to do this, in my opinion, is to expose AllowToShowData  and other configurations like it as an api, make a service that loads that data from the server and then have the controller inject that service. I find mixing of server and client templates harder to maintain, because you are never sure if a bug originated in the server or the client code.
I also avoid using ng-init, and put all my scope management inside the controller, for the same reason.

Comment: I prefer how I do it because I would like that authorization permissions get handled on server side, and only the final values (allowX, doNotAllowY) get  rendered to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angularjs documentation does not recommend to use ng-init 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit.

And I don't like the idea to make an additional ajax call for the configuration values. So, I would propose the following way.

On the view put a configuration section for your controller. Something like this

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        var model = {
            allowToShowData: @AllowToShowData.ToString().ToLower()
        };
    </script>
}
```

and render the html fragment as

```
<div ng-if="allowToShowData"><span ng-bind="mything" /></div>
```

In the angular controller you get the flag value from the model and do a call depending on the flag value and store the flag into `$scope` for using in `ng-if` directive.

```
function MyController($window)
{
    $scope.allowToShowData = $window.model.allowToShowData;
    $scope.myInit = function()
    {
         $http.get("ShowData").success(function() {
             $scope.mything = 123;
         });
    }

    if ($scope.allowToShowData) {
        $scope.myInit();
    }
}
```

And to improve the code style, I would suggest to use method `controller` to create your controllers

```
angular
    .module("yourModuleName")
    .controller("yourControllerName", ["$window", function($window) {
        //your controller code
    }]);
```

See more details here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.

Comment: definitely I already use angular.controller, it was just for shortness :)

Comment: I like your solution, I would simply improve this by renaming model to another more specific name since once you pass thru this page that "global" object model will be alive, so it may be problematic since other places might use this as well. What I dont like is the mixup of the two different paradigms: angular vs plain javascript

Comment: I just realized something: since ASPNET MVC Views reflect as angularjs routes, these get cached in $templateCache. Therefore any usage of this window/scope logic MAY get in trouble. In my case, the flags get their true/false value based on authorization rules so there should not be an issue since the single-page-app instance is per user, and if he logs out, a "new instance" will be obtained if you do a full refresh of the page.